# Merge sort, where are the sublists saved?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I have included the code I am using.

I understand that the start of the code continues splitting the sublists until you have single values. The single values are saved in the variables lefthalf and righthalf and are then merged in sorted order.

How does the code merge two lists of two elements? As I see it these sublists are saved in separate local variables called alist, how are these being merged?

```
def mergeSort(alist):

    if len(alist)>1:
        mid = len(alist)//2
        lefthalf = alist[:mid]
        righthalf = alist[mid:]

        mergeSort(lefthalf)
        mergeSort(righthalf)

        i=0
        j=0
        k=0

        while i < len(lefthalf) and j < len(righthalf):
            if lefthalf[i] < righthalf[j]:
                alist[k]=lefthalf[i]
                i=i+1
            else:
                alist[k]=righthalf[j]
                j=j+1
            k=k+1


        while i < len(lefthalf): 
            alist[k]=lefthalf[i]
            i=i+1
            k=k+1


        while j < len(righthalf):
            alist[k]=righthalf[j]
            j=j+1
            k=k+1
```

Comment: What do you mean by "The single values are saved in the variables lefthalf and righthalf"? `lefthalf` and `righthalf` are lists. `lefthalf = alist[:mid]` creates a copy of the left half of `alist`, saving it as `lefthalf`. Similarly with `righthalf`. Then the recursive calls occur, which sort those two sublists in place.

Comment: I would assume that the space for all those local arrays is allocated from the heap (not the stack). This could be avoided by doing a one time allocation of a second array, and merging back and forth between the two arrays (this can be done with either top down or bottom up merge sort).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first `while` loop pick a smaller smaller item from `lefthalf`, `righthalf` until one of two lists run out. (`lefthalf`, `righthalf` each contains sorted items)

```
while i < len(lefthalf) and j < len(righthalf):
    if lefthalf[i] < righthalf[j]:
        # Pick the smallest item from `leftHalf` if has a smaller item
        alist[k]=lefthalf[i]
        i=i+1
    else:
        # Pick smallest item from `rightHalf`
        alist[k]=righthalf[j]
        j=j+1
    k = k + 1
    # `k` keeps track position of `alist`
    # (where to put the smallest item)
    # Need to increase the `k` for the next item
```

The second, third `while` loops copies remaining items to `alist`. Only one of two loop bodies will be executed; one is exausted in the first `while` loop.

---

SIDE NOTE: `alist[k] = ...` change the item of `alist` in place.

Comment: Note that no merging takes place until recursion reaches a state where there are two sublists of size 1. Only then will the code that does the merging be reached. The merging is done depth first, left first.

Answer (score 3):

So this is a inplace version of `mergeSort`, in that it takes in a list and modifies it to be a sorted version. (Though it involves creating a copy of each half, so it isn't constant space). Here it is commented as to what the code is doing:

```
def mergeSort(alist):

    if len(alist)>1:  # empty lists and lists of one element are sorted already
        mid = len(alist)//2  # find the halfway point
        lefthalf = alist[:mid]  # make a copy of the first half of the list
        righthalf = alist[mid:] # make a copy of the second half of the list 

        mergeSort(lefthalf)
        mergeSort(righthalf)

        # Each half is now sorted

        # Now we're going to copy elements from lefthalf and righthalf
        # back into alist. We do this by keeping three index variables:
        # where we are in lefthalf (i), where we are in righthalf (j)
        # and where we are going to put stuff in alist (k)

        i=0
        j=0
        k=0

        while i < len(lefthalf) and j < len(righthalf):
            # that is, "while we still have stuff left in both halves":

            if lefthalf[i] < righthalf[j]:
                # The thing we're looking at in lefthalf is smaller
                # than what we have in righthalf. Copy the thing in
                # lefthalf over to alist, and increment i
                alist[k]=lefthalf[i]
                i=i+1
            else:
                # same story, but on the right half
                alist[k]=righthalf[j]
                j=j+1
            k=k+1


        # If we ran out of stuff in righthalf first, finish up copying
        # over all the rest of the stuff in lefthalf
        while i < len(lefthalf): 
            alist[k]=lefthalf[i]
            i=i+1
            k=k+1


        # If we ran out of stuff in lefthalf first, finish up copying
        # over all the rest of the stuff in righthalf
        while j < len(righthalf):
            alist[k]=righthalf[j]
            j=j+1
            k=k+1

        # Note that only one of those while loops will actually do anything -
        # the other while loop will have its condition false the first time
```